# Angular 12 Unhandled Promise rejection: Maximum recursion limit reached. ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ;

Tags: javascript, angular, multidimensional-array

Getting error

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Maximum recursion limit reached. ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Maximum recursion limit reached.

while page loads on angular
while clicking on the below side nav.

Sidenav.html

```
<section id="lp-nav" class="lp-sidenav">
    <div uk-sticky="sel-target: .uk-navbar-container; cls-active: uk-navbar-sticky" class="navbar-container">
        <nav class="uk-navbar-container" uk-navbar>
            <div class="lp-navbar">
                <div class="uk-navbar-center">
                    <a class="uk-navbar-toggle" uk-navbar-toggle-icon href="#lp-mobile-nav" uk-toggle></a>
                    <a class="uk-logo uk-logo-icon" href="javascript:;"><img src="assets\images\lp-square.svg"
                            alt="" /></a>
                </div>
                <a class="uk-logo-mini" href="javascript:;"><img src="assets\images\lp-square.svg"
                        alt="" /></a>

                <a class="uk-navbar-item uk-logo" href="javascript:;"><img src="assets\images\hello.svg"
                        alt="" /></a>
                <div class="uk-navbar-item">
                    <ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-default">
                        <li><a href="#" routerLink="/admin/dashboard" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']"><img
                                    src="assets\images\nav/ico-dash.svg" alt="" />
                                <span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" routerLink="/admin/sale"
                                [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']"><img src="assets\images\nav\ico-pos.svg" alt="" />
                                <span>Transactions</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" routerLink="/admin/business" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']"><img
                                    src="assets\images\nav\ico-biz.svg" alt="" />
                                <span>Businesses</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" routerLink="/admin/marketing" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']"><img
                                    src="assets\images\nav\ico-marketing.svg" alt="" />
                                <span>Marketing</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" routerLink="/admin/support" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']"><img
                                    src="assets\images\nav\ico-support.svg" alt="" />
                                <span>Support</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="uk-navbar-item uk-position-bottom-left">
                    <ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-default">

                        <li class="uk-nav-divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="lp-toggle"
                                uk-toggle="target: .lp-sidenav; cls: closed; animation: uk-animation-slide-left"><img
                                    src="assets\images\nav\ico-toggle.svg" alt="" /></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</section>
```

ts file

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidenav',
  templateUrl: './sidenav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidenav.component.scss']
})
export class SidenavComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

And Header html

```
<div class="lp-head">
    <div class="uk-section-title">
        <h1 class="uk-article-title uk-margin-remove">{{name}}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="lp-subnav">
        
        <div class="uk-inline lp-subnav-user">
            <button class="uk-button uk-button-default" type="button" ><img style="display:none" src="assets\images\nav\ico-user.svg"
                    alt="" /><span
                    class="user"><strong>{{userName}}</strong><small>{{userData.merchantName}}</small></span><span
                    uk-icon="icon:  triangle-down"></span></button>
            <div uk-dropdown="mode: click; pos: bottom-justify; offset:4">
                <ul class="uk-nav uk-dropdown-nav">
                    
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="logout()">Log Out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Header.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  name: string;
  

  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute, private store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.name = route.snapshot.firstChild.data.name;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
         
  }

  logout(): void {
    localStorage.clear();
    this.store.dispatch(new LogOutAction());
  }

}
```

And I used bot side nav and header in a separate component.

```
<div class="lp-main-container uk-grid-collapse" uk-height-match uk-grid uk-height-match="target: > div > .uk-card">
    <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
    <section class="lp-section uk-section uk-section-small uk-padding-remove-top uk-width-expand@s"
        uk-height-viewport="expand: true">
        <div class="uk-container lp-dashboard">
            <section>
                <app-header></app-header>
            </section>
            <section>
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            </section>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Now what happens here application runs fine after logging in and while navigating through the side nav components change as per the requirement and header name too. but if I reload the application and navigate through side nav components changes here but the header name remains the same and the console gives the above error.

Comment: Where is your Typescript code? Put more context. There is not enough information

Comment: thanks, @walid for your comment. I added the required code and description.

Comment: The best thing you can do if you want us to help is set up a StackBlitz with the error happening. Try to reduce it to the minimal version that still has that error. Chances are, by doing this, you'll find the solution by yourself